# Capturing stdout to zip and interrupting using CTRL-C gives a corrupted zip file

Tags: c++, linux, signals, gzip, stdout

I am developing a C++ program that can run all day. It outputs to stdout and I want to compress this output. The uncompressed output can be many GB. A startup Bourne shell script compiles the C++ code and starts up the program like so:

`./prog | gzip > output.gz`

When I interrupt the script using CTRL-C, the .gz file is always corrupted.
When I start the program from a terminal and interrupt it using CTRL-C, the .gz file is also always corrupted.
When I start the program a terminal and terminate it using Linux killall, the .gz file is fine.

On the other hand, on a terminal `cat <large_file> | gzip > cat.gz` can be interrupted using CTRL-C and cat.gz is always fine. So I suspect cat has a signal handler of some sort that I have to implement as well in my program in C++... but looking at a cat implementation online, I found nothing like it. Never the less, I implemented this:

```
void SignalHandler(int aSignum)
{
  exit(0);
}

void Signals()
{
  signal(SIGINT,  SignalHandler);
  signal(SIGKILL, SignalHandler);
  signal(SIGTERM, SignalHandler);
}
```

...and even something in the bsh script, but nothing helps. After CTRL-C, the gz file is corrupted.

Questions:

- What does cat have what my program does not?
- How can I terminate my script/program using CTRL-C with the zip file in order?

### Edit 1

Opening the resulting file using `zcat` gives some output, but then:
`gzip: file.gz: unexpected end of file`. Opening it in Ubuntu's Archive Manager just gives a popup saying `An error occurred while extracting files.`

### Edit 2

Tried flushing; no change in the problem was observed.

### Edit 3

More info about the issue: Missing end (EOCDR) signature

```
Fix archive (-F) - assume mostly intact archive
    zip warning: bad archive - missing end signature
    zip warning: (If downloaded, was binary mode used?  If not, the
    zip warning:  archive may be scrambled and not recoverable)
    zip warning: Can't use -F to fix (try -FF)

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (file.gz)
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/temp$ zip -FF file.gz --out file2.gz
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
    zip warning: Missing end (EOCDR) signature - either this archive
                     is not readable or the end is damaged
Is this a single-disk archive?  (y/n): y
  Assuming single-disk archive
Scanning for entries...
    zip warning: zip file empty
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/temp$ ls -lh file2.gz
-rw------- 1 maot maot 22 feb 15 15:18 file2.gz
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/temp$
```

### Edit 4

Thanks @Maxim Egorushkin, but it does not work. The interruption of the script by CTRL-C kills `prog` before the signal handler of the script is executed. Hence, I can not send it a signal, it's already gone... and without output of `SignalHandler`. When `prog` is started from the command line, the output of `SignalHandler` is observed. Prog:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>

void SignalHandler(int aSignum)
{
  std::cout << "prog: Interrupt signal " << aSignum << " received.\n";
  fflush(nullptr);
  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
  for (int sig = 1; sig <=31; sig++)
  {
    std::cout << " sig " << sig;
    signal(sig,  SignalHandler);
  }

  while (true)
  {
    std::cout << "prog: Sleep ";
    fflush(nullptr);
    usleep(1e4);
  }
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

onerror()
{
  echo "onerror(): Started."
  ps -jef | grep prog
  killall -s SIGINT prog
  exit
}

g++ -Wall prog.cpp -o prog

trap onerror 2

prog | gzip > file.gz
```

Result:

```
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/temp$ test.sh 
^Conerror(): Started.
maot     16733 16721 16721  5781  0 16:17 pts/1    00:00:00 grep prog
prog: no process found
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/temp$
```

### Edit 5 minimal working solution

Implementation of the answer of Maxim Egorushkin. Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
g++ -Wall prog.cpp -o prog
prog | setsid gzip > file.gz & wait
```

Prog:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>

void SignalHandler(int aSignum)
{
  std::cout << "prog: Interrupt signal " << aSignum << " received.\n";
  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT,  SignalHandler);

  while (true)
  {
    std::cout << "prog: Sleep ";
    usleep(1e4);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "the file is always corrupted"? What does that mean?

Comment: Did you try to call `flush` before `exit(0)`? It might be that the file is not written fully and some residuals are buffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press Ctrl+C the shell sends `SIGINT` to the **last** process in the pipeline, which is `gzip` here. `gzip` terminates and the next time `prog` writes into `stdout` it receives `SIGPIPE`.

You need to send `SIGINT` to `prog` for it to flush its `stdout` and exit (provided you installed the signal handler as you did), so that `gzip` receives all of its output and then terminates.

---

You can run your pipeline as follows:

```
prog | setsid gzip > file.gz & wait
```

It uses shell job control feature to start the pipeline in the background (that `&` symbol). Then it `wait`s for the job to terminate. On `Ctrl+C` `SIGINT` is sent to the foreground process which is the shell in `wait` and all processes in the same terminal process group (unlike when the pipeline is in the foreground and `SIGINT` is sent only to the last process in the pipeline). `prog` is in that group. But `gzip` is started with `setsid` to place it into another group, so that it doesn't receive `SIGINT` but rather terminates when its `stdin` is closed when `prog` terminated.

Comment: Tried to implement your idea, see above, but to no avail. Can you check?

Comment: @TradingDerivatives.eu Added a solution for you.